# Search bar object nil in UISearchBar textDidChange delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have faced a very strange behavior for textDidChange delegate method of UISearchBar. Here is my code

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    searchText = [searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {

        [self searchedWithText:searchText]; // I am using this method to fetch my search results from coredata

        [searchBar becomeFirstResponder]; // For making the search field active
    }

}

-(void)searchedWithText:(NSString *)searchText {

    // In this method the type of searchText is shown as NSTaggedPointerString and the value is nil

}
```

I did a po for searchBar in the delegate method and I got the below message

```
(lldb) po searchBar
error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): extracting data from value failed
Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of variable searchBar: variable not available
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

My issue is the searchText parameter in my searchedWithText method is nil. So the results from coredata is nil. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: What line of the delegate method are you on?  Can you try it again when you are on the `becomeFirstResponder` method.  Also, can you NSLog the searchBar instead?

Comment: When I am on the line from where I am calling my other method. I gave NSLog for the searchBar and I got proper value
<UISearchBar: 0x7fea0e8c8260; frame = (0 418.5; 375 44); text = 'A'; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fea0e8c44d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea0e8c8600>>

Comment: Make sure that you are attached to Debug version of your application, and compiler optimizations are turned off for debug.

Comment: Is there a problem with the execution of the app or just the po?  I haven't found LLDB to be perfect -- it might not be a problem

Comment: Actually my issue is not the search bar becoming nil. The issue is search key passed to the method is nil